# Ember Quickstart: Build Error when adding JS file to component

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I just started using Ember. The next step in the [Ember Quickstart tutorial](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/getting-started/quick-start/) is adding a JS file to a component:

> In addition to the template, a component can also have a JavaScript
>   file [...]. Go ahead and create a .js file with the same name and in
>   the same directory as our template (app/components/people-list.js),
>   and paste in the following content:

I did that, but now I get a build error:

```
Build Error (broccoli-persistent-filter:TemplateCompiler)

EEXIST: file already exists, symlink '/var/folders/9f/hkp3jgh507ld849g376t8v9c0000gp/T/broccoli-68910fD325sz6drb3/out-131-broccoli_merge_trees_templates/ember-quickstart/templates/components/people-list.js' -> '/var/folders/9f/hkp3jgh507ld849g376t8v9c0000gp/T/broccoli-68910fD325sz6drb3/out-132-broccoli_persistent_filter_template_compiler/ember-quickstart/templates/components/people-list.js'
```

How do I get rid of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm reading the error message correctly both you `people-list.hbs` and `people-list.js` files are in `app/templates/components`. In Ember Octane both files should be moved to `app/components` which is a new feature called component template colocation.

If that isn't the issue you may just need to restart the local ember server (though I haven't had to do that when adding a new `js` file for a component in the past.

Comment: Thanks, that got me on the right track, though there's a similar message if I put both files in `app/components`. I deleted those and did `ember generate component people-list`again. The `js` file was generated in `app/components`, but the `hbs` file in `app/templates/components`. That's the only way it works on my machine.

Comment: what versions of `ember` and `ember-cli` are you using then?

Comment: This says to me that you're using an older version of ember-cli in your app. Check your package.json for the current version of `ember-cli` or run `npx ember-cli-update` from within your quickstart app to upgrade.

Comment: Thanks, I was indeed using an pre-octane version of `ember-cli` (which surprises me as Octane is older than the computer I'm using).